# Problemas para imprimir los datos que agrego en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo mi inserción de datos correctamente, se agregan de forma correcta en la base de datos, pero mi segundo query no entra bien por que no imprime mis datos ni con echo ni printf y no logro encontrar el error.

Este es mi codigo php.

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from CLiente where Nombre='$nom' and Apellido='$ape' and Correo='$cor' and Contrasena='$con' and Telefono='$telf' and Celular='$celu' and CalleNum='$calle' and Colonia='$colo' and Ciudad='$ciud' and Estado='$estado' and CP='$cp'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $total = $row['ID_Cliente'];

    echo $total;
    echo $row['ID_Cliente'];
    echo $row['Nombre'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Te hace falta lo siguiente despues de tu consulta a la base de datos

```
while($fila =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $fila["nombreColumna1"];
    echo $fila["nombreColumna2"];
}
```

- La consulta anterior te devuelve un array de datos, entonces necesitas de un bucle, en este caso `while` para iterar los datos
- `mysqli_fetch_array` obtiene los resultados de tu consulta en forma de array asociativo, por eso le pasamos a dicha función como argumento el nombre de la consulta que es `$result`
- Ahora si por dentro con la variable `$fila` puedes acceder a los nombres de las columnas que te llegan como clave en tu array asociativo
- Sustituye el uso de `["nombreColumna1"]` y `["nombreColumna2"]` por los nombres de las columnas a las cuales deseas acceder de tu tabla

Tu código final debería lucir así:

```
<?php 

$result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from CLiente where Nombre='$nom' and 
                            Apellido='$ape' and Correo='$cor' and 
                            Contrasena='$con' and Telefono='$telf' and 
                            Celular='$celu' and CalleNum='$calle' and 
                            Colonia='$colo' and Ciudad='$ciud' and 
                            Estado='$estado' and CP='$cp'") 
        or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($fila =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $fila["nombreColumna1"];
    echo $fila["nombreColumna2"];
}
```

REFERENCIAS

- [mysql fetch array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Disculpa y es normal que nada mas funcione una vez

Comment: Claro, pero me refieron que vuelvo a cargar la paguina con el arreglo del while y ya no envia nada

Comment: pero si le modifico sin el while tambien lo manda conrrectamente, y si lo vuelvo a cargar ya no lo envia

Comment: @MarioTraz me agradaría que muestres en tu pregunta por ejemplo con una o dos imagenes el comportamiento que mencionas para ver por que ocurre

Comment: ya lo agregue con el codigo completo